Cleaning up redundant groups in LaTeX after peer-review edits
In my work as a copy editor, I often have to deal with "messy" code. During the peer-review process, authors of the articles we publish typically highlight the changes requested by the referees by coloring the added and/or modified text. For instance, they define commands in the preamble like this (although they are usually much more creative):
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

and then they use it as follows:

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae
ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, \red{quia voluptas sit,
aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,} sed quia consequuntur magni dolores
eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est,
qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, \red{adipisci
velit,} sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et
dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

Once the peer-review phase is completed, the paper is sent to me for final formatting. However, the authors often only remove the macro but not the curly braces that delimit its argument:
\red{String} --> {String}


Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem
accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam eaque ipsa, quae
ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta
sunt, explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem, {quia voluptas sit,
aspernatur aut odit aut fugit,} sed quia consequuntur magni dolores
eos, qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt, neque porro quisquam est,
qui dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit, amet, consectetur, {adipisci
velit,} sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt, ut labore et
dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem.

As a result, there are errors in spacing and other formatting issues. Is there any tool or strategy to clean up these unnecessary "groups"?
Note. I use Emacs as my editor and primarily the query-replace-regexp function, but solving this problem using only regular expressions and query-replacement is not satisfactory.

regexp is about all you have, a mult-line regex that matches a brace group that isn't prefixed by a command or starts with a command, should catch most cases, so  match abc {group here} xyz but not  abc \foo{group here} xyz or  abc {\foo group here} xyz  or  abc \foo[t]{group here} xyz

Do you have any control over the instructions given to authors? This wouldn't catch everything because people don't read instructions, but it might help. Then you could tell them to change the definition in the preamble, maybe, but leave \red in the text - or replace \red by \fixed or something. That would make it much easier to remove.

@DavidCarlisle I don't think it's that "simple" (in reality, it already isn't). There are cases like \foo{group here}{group here}{group here}... Sometimes I am tempted to use the "garbage in, garbage out" strategy...

@cfr Yes, of course we have guidelines for the authors... but as you mentioned, they are not followed.

sure but if I wanted to do this I'd match {} groups that were not prefixed by },  ]  or \foo  so none of the groups in your example would match, Of course if \foo is not a 3 argument command but a 0 argument command with three spurious groups following, you lose, but too bad

also of course you can't match a brace group containing arbitrary nested groups with a regex, but you could do it in a bit of lisp or simpler just match groups containing nested groups to a depth of at most 1 or 2 which should cover most cases.

@DavidCarlisle Okay, thanks. I figured there weren't many alternatives. I was hoping someone would pull a rabbit out of the hat.

@Gabriele I realise that. I just wondered if they currently provided an easy way for authors to make life easy for you. If you currently tell them to remove \red and the braces, well, that's a lot more work than just removing \red. But if you put \newcommand\fixed[1]{#1} into the preamble of returned papers and tell them to replace \red by \fixed, that's easy. Sure, some people won't do it, but you might get more people to comply. But, obviously, you might already be providing something even easier.

I would use) emacs 2-window mode, compare the original (with \red still in the file) with the new version that has \red removed.  Of course there will be other differences and it's not automatic, but if you can find where \red has been removed, you at least have a chance to figure out which braces should be removed.  (And contemplate boiling the author in oil.)

@barbarabeeton Thank you, unfortunately we do not have access to the correspondence between the authors and referees so it is not possible to do this manual diff, as you suggested. It would still be a lot of work. If we were to boil in oil all the authors who use LaTeX incorrectly, the scientific world would be drastically reduced... :). (for example, they kill me when they use \def\({\left(}, \def\l{\lambda}...)

@cfr Thanks. I forwarded your suggestions to our editorial office.

As I understood @barbarabeeton, her suggestion was only to contemplate boiling them in oil.

@Gabriele -- You have my total sympathy!  Having to do a complete re-edit isn't fun.  Maybe you could provide some instructions to your referees about making a strong suggestion to authors when such attention-getting methods are used, namely, how to clean up completely.  If uneven spacing still gets to you, you might look for open braces preceded by a space or at the beginning of a line, while simultaneously looking at the output.  Not foolproof, but might locate some of the problems.fairly quickly.  Looking for patterns is never a bad idea.
